# I need to create multiple cluster nodes using VerneMQ, but the docs doesn't specify how to create cluster nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, mqtt-vernemq

I am new to `MQTT`. I have to create multiple vernemq cluster nodes. How do I do this?

```
sudo vmq-admin cluster show
```

produces this output:

```
|      Node       |Running|

|VerneMQ@127.0.0.1| true  |
```

I would like to have one more node added to the cluster, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Well you took the first step, starting a node. Now start a second node. Then use the  `vmq-admin cluster join discovery-node=<OtherClusterNode>` command to tell the nodes to form a cluster.

Documentation is here: `https://docs.vernemq.com/clustering/introduction`

Feel free to improve the documentation if needed!

Comment: Andre F, Thanks for your answer, but how do I start a second node in VerneMQ?

Comment: Conceptually, cluster nodes are different servers. Whether you do this as cloud instances, physical machines, Docker, Kubernetes pods is up to you.

Comment: Andre F, I've used Docker to host and clustering works fine now, Thanks :)